# How to read database name from SQL Server .bak file?

Tags: sql-server

I have SampleDB.bak file. Is it possible to read Db Name within this .bak file without restoring?

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV I think OP wants to get the db name **without** restoring.

Answer (score 6):

Below query will give you the logical file(Data file and Log File) name of the backup.

```
RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK = 'D:\MyBackups\Backup.bak'
```

Fore more info on [FILELISTONLY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms173778.aspx)

Comment: See also [HEADERONLY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178536.aspx) if FILELISTONLY does not have the info you need.

Comment: If you are trying to restore an old .bak file & you are getting an error about the database not matching, even though it does match, try going to Options & clicking the "Overwrite t he existing database(WITH REPLACE)" check box.

Answer (score 6):

You can use below TSQL query

```
RESTORE HEADERONLY FROM DISK='D:\Database\Northwind.bak'
```